# Reorder color and pattern legends in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I use the code below.

The order of the legends on the right is `city`, `split`. How can I reverse the order to `split`, `city`? I tried to use order in `guides()`, but that does not work. How to solve this?

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(ggpattern)
 df <- data.frame(
 no = c(rep("6", 3), "7", rep("8", 6), rep("9", 17), rep("10", 12), rep("11", 21)),
 city = c(rep("Madrid", 47), rep("New York", 13)),
 split = c(rep("blue", 3), rep("blue", 1), rep("blue", 4), rep("red", 2), 
       rep("blue", 2), rep("red", 15), rep("blue", 4), rep("red", 8), 
       rep("blue", 1), rep("red", 7), rep("blue", 2), rep("red", 11)))
 ggplot(data = df, aes(x = no, fill = city, pattern = split)) +
   geom_bar_pattern(
                    color = "black", 
                    pattern_fill = "black",
                    pattern_angle = 45,
                    pattern_density = 0.1,
                    pattern_spacing = 0.01,
                    pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.6) + 
   scale_pattern_manual(values = c(blue = "stripe", red = "none")) + 
   guides(pattern = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "white")),
          fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pattern = "none", order=1), # this line is incorrect?
          pattern = guide_legend(order = 0)   # or this line is incorrect?
           ))
```

Comment: You can convert to `factor` with `levels` specified in a custom order for those columns

Comment: Do you have more details, please? Thank you.

Comment: I meant `df %>% mutate(city = factor(city, levels = c("New York", "Madrid")), split = factor(split, levels = c("red", "blue"))) %>% ggplot(data = ., ...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My slight change to `guides()` results in `split` being displayed above `city` in the legend. Please note the difference in `order`. There is no `order = 0`.

```r
 library(ggplot2)
 library(ggpattern)

 df <- data.frame(
 no = c(rep("6", 3), "7", rep("8", 6), rep("9", 17), rep("10", 12), rep("11", 21)),
 city = c(rep("Madrid", 47), rep("New York", 13)),
 split = c(rep("blue", 3), rep("blue", 1), rep("blue", 4), rep("red", 2), 
       rep("blue", 2), rep("red", 15), rep("blue", 4), rep("red", 8), 
       rep("blue", 1), rep("red", 7), rep("blue", 2), rep("red", 11)))
 ggplot(data = df, aes(x = no, fill = city, pattern = split)) +
   geom_bar_pattern(
                    color = "black", 
                    pattern_fill = "black",
                    pattern_angle = 45,
                    pattern_density = 0.1,
                    pattern_spacing = 0.01,
                    pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.6) + 
   scale_pattern_manual(values = c(blue = "stripe", red = "none")) + 
   guides(pattern = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "white"), order = 2),
          fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pattern = "none", order=1)   
          ))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Just in case you decide you want to reorder the bars in the plot**

```r
 df <- data.frame(
 no = c(rep("6", 3), "7", rep("8", 6), rep("9", 17), rep("10", 12), rep("11", 21)),
 city = c(rep("Madrid", 47), rep("New York", 13)),
 split = c(rep("blue", 3), rep("blue", 1), rep("blue", 4), rep("red", 2), 
       rep("blue", 2), rep("red", 15), rep("blue", 4), rep("red", 8), 
       rep("blue", 1), rep("red", 7), rep("blue", 2), rep("red", 11)))
 
df1 <- df %>% 
   group_by(no) %>% 
   mutate(
     count_no_freq = n()
   )
 
 ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = reorder(no, -count_no_freq), fill = city, pattern = split)) +
   geom_bar_pattern(
                    color = "black", 
                    pattern_fill = "black",
                    pattern_angle = 45,
                    pattern_density = 0.1,
                    pattern_spacing = 0.01,
                    pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.6) + 
   scale_pattern_manual(values = c(blue = "stripe", red = "none")) + 
   guides(pattern = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "white"), order = 2),
          fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pattern = "none", order=1)   
          ))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect.

Comment: You are very welcome. Please consider upvoting and accepting the solution so others can reference it in the future :) To do this, you can click the up arrow and or the checkmark to mark the solution as accepted.

Comment: I upvoted right away, but an answer cannot be accepted after a delay (maybe 5 or 10 minutes or so). Now accepted.

Comment: Hey @SylviaRodriguez - I included some code just in case you want to reorder the bars in descending or ascending order....have a good night! FYI - Removing the `-` in `reorder` will change the ordering.

Comment: Thank you @iamericfletcher This is a beginners question, but how do you change the blue and red colors of the bars to green and brown? I tried, but it does not work for me. Thank you.

Comment: Adding `scale_fill_manual(values = c('brown', 'green'))` above `scale_pattern_manual(values = c(blue = "stripe", red = "none"))` should do it.

Comment: Yes, that worked. I put it in the wrong location. Gracias.